# How to occupy multiple columns or rows in GridLayout with QML?

Tags: qml

i want to know  how to occupy multiple columns or rows in GridLayout.follow is my code .

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
        width: 320
        height: 250

        GridLayout {
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

            rows: 2
            columns: 3

            Button{
                    text: "one"
                }

            Button{
                    text: "two"
                }

            Button{
                    text: "three"
                }

            Button{
                    text: "four"
                }

            Button{
                    text: "five"
                }
                Layout.columnSpan: 2

            }
    }
```

i want to how to make the "five" button occupy two columns. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attached properties `Layout.rowSpan` and `Layout.columnSpan`.
See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#rowSpan-attached-prop) and [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html#columnSpan-attached-prop) for further details.
Also, use `Layout.row` and `Layout.column` to specify the cell in which the item should be placed.
See [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) for further details about how layouts actually work.